# Which utility uses /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, wireless-networking, iproute2

I am attempting to setup a WiFi network with `dnsmasq` on ArchLinux where I have `NetworkManager` and `iproute2` (not `net-tools` anymore in ArchLinux).

As I am reading some tutorials they offen refer to `/etc/network/interfaces` when setting up static ip for the wifi network interface. Is this file relevant also on systems with `net-tools` or should I use `iproute2` CLI to setup the static ip address ?

Answer (score 7):

Both iproute2 and net-tools' ifconfig are low-level tools which can change all the settings directly but don't have any sort of persistent configuration file.

The `interfaces` file is used by "ifupdown", a higher-level network setup tool which only exists on Debian and derivatives – *not* on Arch Linux. (Behind the scenes it *does* use either iproute2 or ifconfig, but that doesn't change anything.)

- The most similar package on Arch would be *netctl*, although it's a bit flimsy.
- Of course, since you already have NetworkManager installed, you could  just use that – but on the other hand it *might* interfere with setting up a Wi-Fi network. (Unless you use NM's built-in hotspot function...) The configuration can be managed via `nmcli`; see also *nm-settings(5)*.
- The other alternative, which comes with Arch, is *systemd-networkd* – it's simple to configure (see the *systemd.network(5)* manual) but its `networkctl` tool is serverely lacking. It does the job fine if you want an interface to be configured *all* the time, though.
- For more complex configurations, you *might* have to write your own script (usually a Type=oneshot systemd service) which directly calls the `ip` and `iw` tools and configures everything.

Comment: `net-tools` has `ifconfig`, `iproute2` has `ip`.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK /etc/network/interfaces is mainly a Debian and descendants thing. I don't have that folder on any of my arch machines.

I'm assuming you're not talking about WiFi here. If you are, have a look at netctl or systemd-networkd.

Assuming you want static configuration, create `/etc/systemd/network/50-wired.network` with the following content (changing Name, Address and Gatway according to your network, of course):

`[Match]
Name=enp1s0
[Network]
Address=10.1.10.9/24
Gateway=10.1.10.1`

Disable NetworkManager:

`# systemctl stop NetworkManager.service`

`# systemctl disable NetworkManager.service`

Enable and start systemd-networkd.service:

`# systemctl start systemd-networkd.service`

`# systemctl enable systemd-networkd.service`

After you have configured dnsmasq to do what you wanted it to, you activate and start it:

`# systemctl start dnsmasq.service`

`# systemctl enable dnsmasq.service`